# Moving data between servers - Is it possible (good idea) to iterate through tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a situation where at two servers (Let's say `A` and `B`) I have a database `db` with the same structure at both of them. I need to create a process which would, every day, iterate through one of the schemas (`x`) and move data from server `A` to server `B`.

So the task came down to creating the loop through tables in `db` and for each of them perform the below operation:

```
insert into B.db.x.tb
select *
 from A.db.x.tb
```

In my case I cannot just create an linked server and use simple stored procedure with a loop. So I am trying to use SSIS.

I tried create an foreach loop with ADO.NET schema Rowset Enumerator. Which would save table names to variable. Unfortunately inside of 'OLE DB Source' I have an error that SSIS cannot retrieve column information...

Could you please advise if that is even possible? or I will have to just list all tables one by one (I would like to avoid that as new tables/columns will be created).

Comment: I would consider using c# to load into a data table and then bulk insert into new database. For SSIS, you will need to have a dataflow for each table.

Comment: You seem to only insert all rows into the target - does that not cause many duplicates over time? Can the target not modify the rows of these tables? And are you making a big assumption here that the schemas for both are exactly the same when this process runs?

Comment: Schema changes or even some duplicates would not be an issue in that case... I will be removing data from a source once that is copied. Didn't mention that because I thought it is irrelevant.